# How to identify with Powershell if Hyper-v VM has reached login screen

Tags: powershell, centos, boot, hyper-v

I have created a CentOS 7 minimal VM running under Hyper-V.  To this I have installed Transmission and set it to start the service on boot using **systemctl enable transmission-daemon.service**

I want to write a powershell script that will start the server, wait until it is active and then open a url to see the Transmission web interface.

I have used **Get-VMIntegrationService** but this returns a value of OK for the heartbeat partway through boot.  I've therefore had to resort to **Start-Sleep** to wait another 15 seconds so that when my script opens the browser it doesn't get a timeout.

Is there a way to establish the login screen has been reached?  Or a more elegant way of doing this?

This is my current startup powershell script:

```
$vmToStart="CentOS_7_minimal"
$url="http://"+$vmToStart+":9091/"  

if ((Get-VMIntegrationService $vmToStart | ?{$_.name -eq "Heartbeat"}).PrimaryStatusDescription -ne "OK") 
{
    Write-Host "Starting Transmission server..." -foregroundcolor "blue"
    start-vm $vmToStart
    do {Start-Sleep -milliseconds 100} 
        until ((Get-VMIntegrationService $vmToStart | ?{$_.name -eq "Heartbeat"}).PrimaryStatusDescription -eq "OK")

    Write-Host "Transmission server started." -foregroundcolor "yellow"
    Write-Host "Starting Transmission service..." -foregroundcolor "blue"
    Start-Sleep -seconds 15
}
Start-Process $url
```

Answer (score 0):

Elegant it is not, but you could simply check if the site you need from the VM is available by just polling for it. The [.NET Webclient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) is quite straightforward to use. See my example below.

```
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"

Do {
     Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

     try { $content = $webClient.DownloadString($url) }
     catch { Write-Host "Page not yet retrieved . . ."}
} While ( $content -eq $null)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Far more elegant than waiting a hard coded amount of time.